# Is it possible to serialize single unit of class array, in order to send it to another activity?

Tags: android, class, serialization

I'm trying to pass Faults[current] single class to Fault_Page activity. But encountered

> Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object
>   caused by 
>   java.io.NotSerializableException

at here in OnCreate function

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Select_Click();
        }
    });
public void Select_Click(){
    Intent FaultPage=new Intent(this,Fault_Page.class);
    Fault send=Faults[current_swap];
    FaultPage.putExtra("FaultClass", send);
    startActivity(FaultPage);
}
int fault_number=15;
class Fault implements Serializable{
    public String fault_name="Not known";
    public int L_number=0,T_number=0;

    public void Record(){};//currently empty functions

    public void Save(){};

    public void Delete(){};
}
Fault[] Faults;
Faults=new Fault[15];
    for(int i=0;i<Faults.length;i++){
        Faults[i]=new Fault();
    }
```

I searched similar problems and their answers. But fault, mostly occur, was declaring inner class without implements, which is different than me. I even changed my MainActivity class to Serializable. But error still occur in StartActivity function. Can strings be serialized? or something else am i missing?

Comment: Yes, String can be serialized.  I think the problem might be, intent can carry Parcelable Objects. Why don't you try to convert `class Fault implements Parcelable` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises because your inner class `Fault` is not declared `static`.

An inner class always has an implicit reference to its enclosing class, so when the inner class instance is serialized, its enclosing class instance must also be serialized. And I'm betting the enclosing class doesn't implement `Serializable`.  That's okay; you wouldn't want it to anyway.

To get you going, you can just declare `Fault` like this:

```
    static class Fault implements Serializable {
```

That will get you past the `NotSerializableException`.